# await command error, i don't know how to fix it

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format (client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if 'message'.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await 'message'.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

I tried to "fix" the await command but when i did that it said that message was unidentified and I'm very confused how to do it.

Comment: What's the error? Please post the full traceback.

Comment: In your own words: what do you expect `'message'.content.startswith('$hello'):` to mean? Do you expect it to mean the same thing as `message.content.startswith('$hello'):`? If so, why? (Do you see the difference between the two? Hint: look at how Stack Overflow syntax-colours your code.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "but when i did that it said that message was unidentified and I'm very confused how to do it." Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146. When you are asking about an error message, copy and paste the complete error message, formatted as code. For Python, this means start at the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` and copy all the way to the end.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your indentation and `message` should not be a string, its a parameter. Also there were unnecessary backslashes in `client.run()`

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format (client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

Comment: THe indentation is a copying error. The new Stacks editor messes everything up when you try to paste code.

Comment: Oh, I see. That's okay then.